# How to convert integer into Month & Year format

Tags: python, datetime, indexing, formatting, monthcalendar

I have a dataset in Excel CSV where the index is represented by date, but it's in the format given below:

```
201001
201002
201003 and so on..
```

So it's in the format of YYYYMM. I need to convert it into `datetime` format in Python.

Comment: What are you supposed to get for the day of the month?

Comment: `year,month = divmod(n,100)`

Comment: @Andrei I dont need Day of the month. But for coding purpose i can take it as 15th of every month.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert these to date times using [`strptime()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime).

```
from datetime import datetime 

data = ['201001', '201002', '201003']
dt = [datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m') for s in data]
```

**Output**

```
[datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 1, 0, 0)]
```

The string `'%Y%m` tells the function that the dates are formatted as `YYYYMM`. There's a handy reference of `strftime` and `strptime` directives at [strftime.org](https://strftime.org/).

**Edit:**

If your data class is a float or an integer you first need to convert them to strings before using `strptime()`. To do this you could simply call `str()` inside the list comprehension.

```
data = [201001, 201002, 201003]
dt = [datetime.strptime(str(s), '%Y%m') for s in data]
```

Comment: I am getting an error. (strptime() argument 1 must be str, not int). And here i am trying to convert an entire column of the dataset.

Comment: Your data is in an integer format and not a string. Change this line `dt = [datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m') for s in data] ` to `dt = [datetime.strptime(str(s), '%Y%m') for s in data] `. This will convert the integers to strings before formatting. I've edited the answer to show this.

Comment: Although the edited one did not show any error, but the output was same for all the data points. Let me give you the actual form here. I have a "dataset" in which i  have a column "Date" which contains the integer format of the dates. And i have to convert the entire column, so according to your code, i am writing: dataset.Date=[datetime.strptime(str(s), '%Y%m') for s in dataset.Date]      I may be wrong, actually i am new to python and stuff. so please dont mind my petty mistakes.

Comment: @SpandanRout What does _dataset_ mean? What data structure is it?

Comment: its a dataframe by the name of "Dataset"

Comment: @SpandanRout _DataFrame_ is the important part. You’re creating is using `pandas.read_csv()`? Actually, could you just include all your code and data in your post? It will make things **much** simpler. See: [mcve].

Comment: yes i am importing using pd.read_csv() and assigning it a name i.e. "dataset". and it has 3 columns out of which one is the "Date" column and i want to change the format of the entries in that column. Sorry but i cannot post the data here.

Comment: `dataset.Date = [datetime.strptime(str(s), '%Y%m') for s in dataset.Date]` should work fine. Can you share a snippet of your data to your question by printing `dataset.Date[0:5]`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```py
from datetime import date
myint=201001
mydate=date(myint//100, myint%100, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
dd = 201001
dd = str(dd)
yer=dd[:4]
mn=dd[4:]
newformat=str(yer)+'-'+str(mn)
```

Comment: That doesn’t create a date object of any kind, just a string with a dash in the middle....